# Executing Junit4 tests from a test suite by referring other test suites

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have two test suite files:-

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ GetOrdersTest.class })

public class OrderTestSuite {

}


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ CreateSellerTest.class, GetSellerTest.class, UpdateSellerTest.class, ValidateSellerTest.class })

public class SellerTestSuite {

}
```

My intention is to have a `AllTestSuite` that will execute all tests defined in all other child test suites:-

Right now to achieve this I have to repeat the test classes name again in `AllTestSuite` like below:-

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ GetOrdersTest.class, CreateSellerTest.class, GetSellerTest.class, UpdateSellerTest.class,
    ValidateSellerTest.class })

public class AllTestSuite {

}
```

Is there a way I can just specify the suite name (rather than the actual test classes name) in `AllTestSuite` which will execute all tests specified in the child suites. I tried adding suite name under `@SuiteClasses` as shown below. But it is not working:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ SellerTestSuite.class, OrderTestSuite.class })

public class AllTestSuite {

}
```

I am using `Junit 4.12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried calling two test suites from another test suite class and it works perfectly fine. Please take a look at the code [here](https://gist.github.com/coding963/478b2c67a46d60f54095635cfd8fe232).

All test classes are placed in the com.test package and all test suites are called.